# No conflicts with the variable decleare inside the main and the one decleare inside the namspace

Tags: c++, namespaces

I'm studying c++ namespace and i made a simple code to understand it. In particular i made this code and i don't understand why it doesn't give me the compiler error that i'have already decleare the variable 'a'. Is the compiler help me in some way?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
namespace funzioni_e_altro
{
    int a=5;
    int b=20;
    int c=10;
}
int main()
{
    using namespace funzioni_e_altro;
    int a=0;
    cout<<funzioni_e_altro::a<<"\n";
    cout<<b<<"\n";
    cout<<a<<"\n";
 return 0;
}
```

I expect it gave me a compiler error, but it gave me the outputs: 
5 
20 
0

Comment: namespace funzioni_e_altro literally traslated from italian to english means functions_and_other

Comment: These variables inside the namespace are global. By `int a=0;` you declare new variable, which is 'visible' only in `main` and by calling `a` in `main` you access your new variable in `main`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A using directive makes the names in the namespace available for unqualified name lookup. But it doesn't introduce any new declarations into the block. When you declare `a` in `main` it **hides** the name the using directive could have brought in. That `a` is no longer considered during unqualified name lookup inside `main`.

So when you write `a` in `main`, it can only refer to the local variable. Same as if there was no using directive present at all in `main`.

This behavior is intended. It prevents complete an utter chaos from happening. A using directive should not prevent code from declaring a name in its own scope if it needs to. And you may always refer to the variable in the namespace by *fully* qualifying its name.